# MySql create record with IF statement

Tags: mysql

SQL Query Forum 20210309
I’m building a Firebase Functions application that talks to a Google Cloud SQL database running MySQL 5.7. I’m trying to retrieve a value from a row in one table and, if it exists (the row or the value), insert a record in a different table.
Based on some examples I found online, my code looks like this:

```
DECLARE meeting_link varchar(2048) DEFAULT ""; SELECT meeting_link from campaigns where id=2 INTO meeting_link; IF LENGTH(meeting_link) > 0 THEN INSERT INTO clicks (target_id, ip_address, user_agent) VALUES (38, "ip-address", "user-agent") END IF;
```

In all of the different versions of this I tried, I get an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE meeting_link varchar(2048) DEFAULT ""; SELECT meeting_link from campaigns' at line 1
```

Looking around some more, I found posts that say I can’t use DECLARE in anything but stored procedures, but I can use local variables (@ml for example) but I can’t seem to get that working correctly either.

Can someone please help me with the SQL I need for this?  I need to create the record only if the record in the query exists and return the meeting_link value to my calling program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this documentation page:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html

> This section describes the syntax for the BEGIN ... END compound statement and other statements that can be used in the body of stored programs

That includes `DECLARE` and also `IF/THEN/ELSE/END` constructions. You can't use those outside of stored routines.

Here's a trick you can use instead of a stored routine:

```
SELECT meeting_link from campaigns where id=2 INTO @meeting_link; 

INSERT INTO clicks (target_id, ip_address, user_agent) 
SELECT 38, 'ip-address', 'user-agent' FROM dual WHERE LENGTH(@meeting_link) > 0;
```

You can use `@meeting_link` which is a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), not a declared local variable.

Then instead of using `IF`, use `FROM dual WHERE ...` for your condition. The `dual` table is normally a pseudo-table that doesn't really exist but querying it returns 1 row. But you can make that zero rows if the condition in the `WHERE` clause isn't satisfied.

So the INSERT will conditionally create either one or zero rows.

---

Re your comment:

If you need this to be done in a single SQL statement, then one option would be to make that single SQL statement `CALL` a procedure that you create in your MySQL database.  Then at least you could use `DECLARE` and `IF` like you were intending.

Another alternative is to combine the two statements I show above like this:

```
INSERT INTO clicks (target_id, ip_address, user_agent) 
  SELECT 38, 'ip-address', 'user-agent' 
  FROM campaigns WHERE id=2 AND LENGTH(meeting_link) > 0;
```

This works because even though you query the `campaigns` table, it's not mandatory to select the columns of that table. You can select constant values instead. The conditions in the `WHERE` clause will make this return either one row or zero rows.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thanks for sharing it. I tried it out and it doesn't work. Here's my query: 

SELECT meeting_link from campaigns where id=2 INTO @meeting_link; INSERT INTO clicks (target_id, ip_address, user_agent) SELECT 38, "ip-addr", "user-agent" FROM dual WHERE LENGTH(@meeting_link) > 0;

but I get an error:

ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO clicks (target_id, ip_address, user_agent) SELECT 38, "2603:6080:f40' at line 1

Comment: Most query interfaces only allow one SQL statement at a time. You'll have to run the `SELECT ...INTO` and then using the same connection reference your user-defined variable in a subsequent `INSERT` query.

Comment: I'm doing all of this via Firebase Functions, I'm trying to send one SQL statement to do both, I don't know how to do this across multiple connection references.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I refactored my code to do it a different way.